# Naming a dataframe using a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a loop to create multiple dataframes from CSV files The issue I am facing is naming the dataframe at the end with a variable.

```
list = [1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv]

from x in list:
   name = x.split('.')
   name = pd.read_csv(x)
```

How do I make the name of the dataframe 1 , 2, 3 ?

Comment: Use a `dict` or just a list.

Comment: Yes, I saw that question. Maybe I am doing it wrongly but.
Suppose val = [a, b, c] 

val[1] = 2.csv
but not b = 2.csv ?